# Missing ) after arguement list. (line 6 file "code")

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm new to coding and a got this pre set code to use within a spreadsheet for a google awesome table, and I keep getting this error.

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 6, file "Code)

Here is my code:

```
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/a/waitrose.co.uk/forms/d/11-z44oW1ixP1tShkwjrBpa0DptOA2IinU5MCCkUvf0o/viewform';
var sheetName = 'Form responses 1';
var columnIndex = 5;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Form responses 1);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && (data[i][columnIndex-1] == '' || !data[i][columnIndex-1])) {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex).setValue('<div style="width:100px"><a href="' + editResponseUrl + '" target="_blank">Edit entry</a></div>'); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Form responses 1`? Should it be quoted `"Form responses 1"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a pair of quotes on line 6:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Form responses 1);
```

should be

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
```